# Clustered Index Scan vs Index Seek

Tags: sql-server

Will including more columns in the clustered index for a table increase the chance of turning index scans into index seeks? I'm trying to increase responsiveness with operations involved with a heavily read table. It has 199 columns and currently 65k rows, is it even worth it?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT T1.SALESID,T1.SALESNAME,T1.RESERVATION,T1.CUSTACCOUNT,T1.INVOICEACCOUNT,T1.DELIVERYDATE,T1.URL,T1.PURCHORDERFORMNUM,T1.SALESGROUP,T1.FREIGHTSLIPTYPE,T1.DOCUMENTSTATUS,T1.INTERCOMPANYORIGINALSALESID,T1.CURRENCYCODE,T1.PAYMENT,T1.CASHDISC,T1.TAXGROUP,T1.LINEDISC,T1.CUSTGROUP,T1.DISCPERCENT,T1.INTERCOMPANYORIGINALCUSTACCOUNT,T1.PRICEGROUPID,T1.MULTILINEDISC,T1.ENDDISC,T1.CUSTOMERREF,T1.LISTCODE,T1.DLVTERM,T1.DLVMODE,T1.PURCHID,T1.SALESSTATUS,T1.MARKUPGROUP,T1.SALESTYPE,T1.SALESPOOLID,T1.POSTINGPROFILE,T1.TRANSACTIONCODE,T1.INTERCOMPANYAUTOCREATEORDERS,T1.INTERCOMPANYDIRECTDELIVERY,T1.INTERCOMPANYDIRECTDELIVERYORIG,T1.SETTLEVOUCHER,T1.INTERCOMPANYALLOWINDIRECTCREATION,T1.INTERCOMPANYALLOWINDIRECTCREATIONORIG,T1.DELIVERYNAME,T1.ONETIMECUSTOMER,T1.COVSTATUS,T1.COMMISSIONGROUP,T1.PAYMENTSCHED,T1.INTERCOMPANYORIGIN,T1.EMAIL,T1.FREIGHTZONE,T1.RETURNITEMNUM,T1.CASHDISCPERCENT,T1.CONTACTPERSONID,T1.DEADLINE,T1.PROJID,T1.INVENTLOCATIONID,T1.ADDRESSREFTABLEID,T1.VATNUM,T1.PORT,T1.INCLTAX,T1.NUMBERSEQUENCEGROUP,T1.FIXEDEXCHRATE,T1.LANGUAGEID,T1.AUTOSUMMARYMODULETYPE,T1.SALESORIGINID,T1.ESTIMATE,T1.TRANSPORT,T1.PAYMMODE,T1.PAYMSPEC,T1.FIXEDDUEDATE,T1.EXPORTREASON,T1.STATPROCID,T1.INTERCOMPANYCOMPANYID,T1.INTERCOMPANYPURCHID,T1.INTERCOMPANYORDER,T1.DLVREASON,T1.QUOTATIONID,T1.RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED,T1.RECEIPTDATECONFIRMED,T1.SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED,T1.SHIPPINGDATECONFIRMED,T1.ITEMTAGGING,T1.CASETAGGING,T1.PALLETTAGGING,T1.ADDRESSREFRECID,T1.CUSTINVOICEID,T1.INVENTSITEID,T1.DEFAULTDIMENSION,T1.CREDITCARDCUSTREFID,T1.SHIPCARRIERACCOUNT,T1.SHIPCARRIERID,T1.SHIPCARRIERFUELSURCHARGE,T1.SHIPCARRIERBLINDSHIPMENT,T1.SHIPCARRIERDELIVERYCONTACT,T1.CREDITCARDAPPROVALAMOUNT,T1.CREDITCARDAUTHORIZATION,T1.RETURNDEADLINE,T1.RETURNREPLACEMENTID,T1.RETURNSTATUS,T1.RETURNREASONCODEID,T1.CREDITCARDAUTHORIZATIONERROR,T1.SHIPCARRIERACCOUNTCODE,T1.RETURNREPLACEMENTCREATED,T1.SHIPCARRIERDLVTYPE,T1.DELIVERYDATECONTROLTYPE,T1.SHIPCARRIEREXPEDITEDSHIPMENT,T1.SHIPCARRIERRESIDENTIAL,T1.MATCHINGAGREEMENT,T1.SYSTEMENTRYSOURCE,T1.SYSTEMENTRYCHANGEPOLICY,T1.MANUALENTRYCHANGEPOLICY,T1.DELIVERYPOSTALADDRESS,T1.SHIPCARRIERPOSTALADDRESS,T1.SHIPCARRIERNAME,T1.WORKERSALESTAKER,T1.SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,T1.BANKDOCUMENTTYPE,T1.SALESUNITID,T1.SMMSALESAMOUNTTOTAL,T1.SMMCAMPAIGNID,T1.CASHDISCBASEDATE,T1.CASHDISCBASEDAYS,T1.PDSBATCHATTRIBAUTORES,T1.PDSCUSTREBATEGROUPID,T1.PDSREBATEPROGRAMTMAGROUP,T1.WORKERSALESRESPONSIBLE,T1.AA_INITIALCONDITION,T1.AA_MATERIAL,T1.AA_PONUMBER,T1.AA_REFERENCENUMBER,T1.AA_FINALCONDITION,T1.AA_TEMPLATEID,T1.AA_PRIME,T1.AA_CONTAINER,T1.AA_ENTEREDDATE,T1.AA_ENTEREDDATETZID,T1.AA_EXPEDITE,T1.AA_PROMISEDDATE,T1.AA_PROMISEDDATETZID,T1.AA_GROSSWEIGHT,T1.AA_ALLOY,T1.AA_ITAR,T1.AA_EAR,T1.AA_GSI,T1.AA_SOLUTIONTREAT,T1.AA_BASICFORMID,T1.AA_PLANNEDBY,T1.AA_CLASSIFICATION,T1.INVENTPACKINGMATERIALCODE,T1.AA_CSI,T1.AA_QTY,T1.AA_BILLINGADDRESS,T1.AA_PROCESSMASTER,T1.AA_BILLINGNAME,T1.AA_PACKAGING,T1.AA_HIDECERTMEASURE,T1.AA_INVOICEAPPROVED,T1.AA_PROSHIPMEMOPRINTED,T1.AA_CERTIFIEDDATE,T1.TRI_OPSTATUS,T1.MODIFIEDDATETIME,T1.MODIFIEDBY,T1.CREATEDDATETIME,T1.CREATEDBY,T1.RECVERSION,T1.PARTITION,T1.RECID,T2.PERSON,T2.RECVERSION,T2.RECID,T3.LOCATION,T3.ADDRESS,T3.VALIDFROM,T3.VALIDFROMTZID,T3.VALIDTO,T3.VALIDTOTZID,T3.COUNTRYREGIONID,T3.RECVERSION,T3.RECID,T4.ADDRESS,T4.COUNTRYREGIONID,T4.LOCATION,T4.VALIDFROM,T4.VALIDFROMTZID,T4.RECVERSION,T4.RECID,T5.LOCATION,T5.ADDRESS,T5.VALIDFROM,T5.VALIDFROMTZID,T5.RECVERSION,T5.RECID,T6.NAME,T6.RECID,T6.RECVERSION,T6.INSTANCERELATIONTYPE,T6.NAMESEQUENCE,T6.RECVERSION,T6.RECID,T7.DESCRIPTION,T7.LOCATIONID,T7.RECVERSION,T7.RECID,T8.DESCRIPTION,T8.LOCATIONID,T8.RECVERSION,T8.RECID,T1.AA_COMMENTS FROM  SALESTABLE T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN HCMWORKER T2 ON ((T2.PARTITION=@P1) AND ((T1.WORKERSALESTAKER=T2.RECID) AND (T1.WORKERSALESTAKER=T2.RECID))) LEFT OUTER JOIN LOGISTICSPOSTALADDRESS T3 ON ((T3.PARTITION=@P2) AND ((T1.DELIVERYPOSTALADDRESS=T3.RECID) AND ((1=@P3 OR (T3.ISPRIVATE=@P4)) OR (T3.PRIVATEFORPARTY=@P5)))) LEFT OUTER JOIN LOGISTICSPOSTALADDRESS T4 ON ((T4.PARTITION=@P6) AND ((T1.SHIPCARRIERPOSTALADDRESS=T4.RECID) AND ((1=@P7 OR (T4.ISPRIVATE=@P8)) OR (T4.PRIVATEFORPARTY=@P9)))) LEFT OUTER JOIN LOGISTICSPOSTALADDRESS T5 ON ((T5.PARTITION=@P10) AND ((T1.AA_BILLINGADDRESS=T5.RECID) AND ((1=@P11 OR (T5.ISPRIVATE=@P12)) OR (T5.PRIVATEFORPARTY=@P13)))) LEFT OUTER JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE T6 ON ((((T6.PARTITION=@P14) AND (T6.INSTANCERELATIONTYPE IN (@P15,@P16,@P17,@P18,@P19,@P20,@P21) )) AND ((T2.PERSON=T6.RECID) AND (T2.PERSON=T6.RECID))) AND (T6.INSTANCERELATIONTYPE IN (2975) )) LEFT OUTER JOIN LOGISTICSLOCATION T7 ON ((T7.PARTITION=@P22) AND (T3.LOCATION=T7.RECID)) LEFT OUTER JOIN LOGISTICSLOCATION T8 ON ((T8.PARTITION=@P23) AND (T5.LOCATION=T8.RECID)) WHERE (((T1.PARTITION=@P24) AND (T1.DATAAREAID=@P25)) AND (( NOT ((T1.RETURNSTATUS=@P26)) AND  NOT ((T1.RETURNSTATUS=@P27))) AND (((((((((((((((((((((((((T1.SALESNAME=@P28) AND (T1.SALESID=@P29)) AND (T2.PERSON IS NULL)) AND (T3.LOCATION=@P30)) AND (T3.VALIDFROM=@P31)) AND (T4.LOCATION IS NULL)) AND (T5.LOCATION=@P32)) AND (T5.VALIDFROM=@P33)) AND (T6.NAME IS NULL)) AND (T6.NAMESEQUENCE IS NULL)) AND (T7.LOCATIONID=@P34)) AND (T8.LOCATIONID>=@P35)) OR (((((((((((T1.SALESNAME=@P36) AND (T1.SALESID=@P37)) AND (T2.PERSON IS NULL)) AND (T3.LOCATION=@P38)) AND (T3.VALIDFROM=@P39)) AND (T4.LOCATION IS NULL)) AND (T5.LOCATION=@P40)) AND (T5.VALIDFROM=@P41)) AND (T6.NAME IS NULL)) AND (T6.NAMESEQUENCE IS NULL)) AND (T7.LOCATIONID>@P42))) OR ((((((((((T1.SALESNAME=@P43) AND (T1.SALESID=@P44)) AND (T2.PERSON IS NULL)) AND (T3.LOCATION=@P45)) AND (T3.VALIDFROM=@P46)) AND (T4.LOCATION IS NULL)) AND (T5.LOCATION=@P47)) AND (T5.VALIDFROM=@P48)) AND (T6.NAME IS NULL)) AND  NOT ((T6.NAMESEQUENCE IS NULL)))) OR ((((((((((T1.SALESNAME=@P49) AND (T1.SALESID=@P50)) AND (T2.PERSON IS NULL)) AND (T3.LOCATION=@P51)) AND (T3.VALIDFROM=@P52)) AND (T4.LOCATION IS NULL)) AND (T5.LOCATION=@P53)) AND (T5.VALIDFROM=@P54)) AND (T6.NAME IS NULL)) AND  NOT ((T6.RECID IS NULL)))) OR (((((((((T1.SALESNAME=@P55) AND (T1.SALESID=@P56)) AND (T2.PERSON IS NULL)) AND (T3.LOCATION=@P57)) AND (T3.VALIDFROM=@P58)) AND (T4.LOCATION IS NULL)) AND (T5.LOCATION=@P59)) AND (T5.VALIDFROM=@P60)) AND  NOT ((T6.NAME IS NULL)))) OR ((((((((T1.SALESNAME=@P61) AND (T1.SALESID=@P62)) AND (T2.PERSON IS NULL)) AND (T3.LOCATION=@P63)) AND (T3.VALIDFROM=@P64)) AND (T4.LOCATION IS NULL)) AND (T5.LOCATION=@P65)) AND (T5.VALIDFROM>@P66))) OR (((((((T1.SALESNAME=@P67) AND (T1.SALESID=@P68)) AND (T2.PERSON IS NULL)) AND (T3.LOCATION=@P69)) AND (T3.VALIDFROM=@P70)) AND (T4.LOCATION IS NULL)) AND (T5.LOCATION>@P71))) OR (((((((T1.SALESNAME=@P72) AND (T1.SALESID=@P73)) AND (T2.PERSON IS NULL)) AND (T3.LOCATION=@P74)) AND (T3.VALIDFROM=@P75)) AND (T4.LOCATION IS NULL)) AND  NOT ((T4.VALIDFROM IS NULL)))) OR ((((((T1.SALESNAME=@P76) AND (T1.SALESID=@P77)) AND (T2.PERSON IS NULL)) AND (T3.LOCATION=@P78)) AND (T3.VALIDFROM=@P79)) AND  NOT ((T4.LOCATION IS NULL)))) OR (((((T1.SALESNAME=@P80) AND (T1.SALESID=@P81)) AND (T2.PERSON IS NULL)) AND (T3.LOCATION=@P82)) AND (T3.VALIDFROM>@P83))) OR ((((T1.SALESNAME=@P84) AND (T1.SALESID=@P85)) AND (T2.PERSON IS NULL)) AND (T3.LOCATION>@P86))) OR (((T1.SALESNAME=@P87) AND (T1.SALESID=@P88)) AND  NOT ((T2.PERSON IS NULL)))) OR ((T1.SALESNAME=@P89) AND (T1.SALESID>@P90))) OR (T1.SALESNAME>@P91)))) ORDER BY T1.SALESNAME,T1.SALESID,T2.PERSON,T3.LOCATION,T3.VALIDFROM,T4.LOCATION,T4.VALIDFROM,T5.LOCATION,T5.VALIDFROM,T6.NAME,T6.RECID,T6.NAMESEQUENCE,T7.LOCATIONID,T8.LOCATIONID OPTION(FAST 2)
```

Comment: For such a small table it's quite simple to test what affect it has. If you want ideas how to improve the query, you should at least upload the query plan + table / index structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to pick the columns in a Clustered Index. It always includes all columns.

In case you meant *key columns*: There is no "chance" here. It depends on the query whether an index is a good fit or not. Without schema and query nothing can be said. Refer to pretty much any indexing tutorial to answer this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Will adding more columns to the clustered index *key*, aka Primary Key, possibly turn Index Scans into Index Seeks? Yes, but query tuning via Primary Key can create other complications. It may be less painful to just add a Non Clustered Index on the columns that you want "seeked".

Can you provide the problem query?